# How can I lookup US county from latitude/longitude?

Tags: addresses, geocoding, county

Does there exist an easy way to look up U.S. counties from latitude/longitude?  I know about Mathieu's excellent [Region Lookup extension](https://github.com/mlutfy/ca.bidon.regionlookup), but since one postal code can encompass multiple counties, I'd like something more definitive.

I know that Google Maps lookups can give you county names - has anyone tried pulling that into CiviCRM on geocode lookup?

Answer (score 3):

I've never done it, but I think Tyrell's [SmartyStreets extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/smartystreets) provides it.

One thing to point out, however, for anyone who does it another way: county names repeat a lot, and the ID numbers of counties in CiviCRM are totally arbitrary, unlike states.  The way to look up county is to find the state and then find the county name within the state.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  I noticed in the SmartyStreets extension docs that non-profits can get free accounts, but I couldn't find a reference to that on their site.  Do you know if that's still true?

Comment: No idea. I think there may have been a special page for nonprofits.